# Jquery - generating nested lists from SQLite

Tags: jquery, html, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a group collapsible list view in jquery mobile using data retrieved via SQLite.

My data looks something like this:

```
Letter |  Number
A      |  1
A      |  2
B      |  3
B      |  4
C      |  5
```

I want a 'Letter' for each header group which is collapsible, and the various corresponding 'Number' to be a child of each group. **Both the header and the subsequent children should be ordered ascending (children within their respective groups).**

So essentially the final result in HTML will look something like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="LetterList" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="false">

<div data-role="collapsible" class="collapseclass">
<h2>A</h2>
<ul data-role="listview">
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" class="collapseclass">
<h2>B</h2>
<ul data-role="listview">
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" class="collapseclass">
<h2>C</h2>
<ul data-role="listview">
<li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

I have attempted creating the headers first, by querying a distinct list of Letter, then inserting the divs:

```
function querySuccessDistinctLetter(tx, result) {

        $('#LetterList').empty();
        $.each(result.rows, function (index) {
            var row = result.rows.item(index);
            $('#LetterList').append('<div data-role="collapsible" class="collapseclass"><h2>' + row['Letter'] + '</h2></div>');
        });

}
```

But now I am stumped as to how I can insert the 'Number' children under each header? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with one query. Make sure to sort by letter then number in the query so the result looks like this:

```
var result = {
  rows: [
    {Letter: "A", number: 1},
    {Letter: "A", number: 2},
    {Letter: "B", number: 3},
    {Letter: "B", number: 4},
    {Letter: "B", number: 5},
  ]
};
```

Then build the HTML markup by stepping through the rows and seeing when the letter changes:

```
  var curLetter;
  var html = '';
  $('#LetterList').empty();
  for (var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
    var row = result.rows[i];
    var letter = row.Letter;
    var number = row.number;

    if (letter != curLetter){
      if (i > 0) html += '</ul></div>';
      curLetter = letter;
      html += '<div data-role="collapsible" class="collapseclass"><h2>' + letter + '</h2><ul data-role="listview">';
    }
    html += '<li><a href="#">' + number + '</a></li>'       
  }
  $('#LetterList').append(html).enhanceWithin();
```

## **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/MmyRoE)**

Comment: You are a genius - thank you! Note that I had to change var html; to var html = ''; to avoid an undefined value and move the html variable under var curLetter'

Comment: @Ralph, thanks. My mistake on the html variable. I have updated the answer and demo for future searchers.